# Apache rewrite module: how to remove '.php' in the middle of the URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I would like this address:

```
http://www.example.com/account/?a=b&c=d
```

to be translated internally as

```
http://www.example.com/account.php/?a=b&c=d
```

using the rewrite module syntax in the .htaccess file.

Any help, please?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^account/ account.php
```